# Django: How to filter foreign key in admin detail view

Tags: django, admin

core/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Entity(models.Model):
    is_person = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entities'

def post_save_person_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        entity, is_created = Entity.objects.get_or_create(is_person=True, person=instance, company=None, name=instance.last_name) # noqa

post_save.connect(post_save_person_receiver, sender=Person)

def post_save_company_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        entity, is_created = Entity.objects.get_or_create(is_person=False, person=None, company=instance, name=instance.short_name) # noqa

post_save.connect(post_save_company_receiver, sender=Company)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_individual = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Entity, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("entity", "group")
```

For every Company and Person created, an Entity is automatically created where Entity.is_person=True if it's a Person. An Entity can then become a member of a Group such as 'Employee', 'Supplier' and 'Customer' through a ManyToMany relationship in the Membership Model.

How do I filter Membership.entity in Admin View (for add and update) that when the Group selected is an 'is_individual=True', such as 'Employee', Entity Field only shows 'is_person=True' Persons in the Entity combobox?

[Admin View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRkAe.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider writing your own view for this. In my opinion, Djangos admin is not a good site to base a frontend on. I use it only for making quick changes where validation doesn't need to be done as much because the users of admin should know what they're doing. When you start adding more responsive stuff, that's when I consider using another view and starting from scratch (or a framework) but a different view none-the-less.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different names for what it sounds like you want: dependent dropdowns, chained fields, etc. Django itself doesn't have anything out of the box for this.

Your 2 options are: (1) do it yourself or (2) use a 3rd-party package.

As far as doing it yourself goes, you're going to need to do some work in JS for making it work on the frontend, and you're probably going to need some kind of flexible view that outputs JSON data, and you're going to need some kind of custom select field to handle this.

For using a 3rd-party package, I don't see anything particularly recent that does this. Here's one that's a few years old: https://github.com/runekaagaard/django-admin-flexselect

Hope this helps some!

Comment: Will look into the link for reference to own view. Thanks.